# My alert does not pop up when I click submit. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, validation

I want my alert to pop up when the form does not validate. It should pop up an alert message when it is valid but does not. I am at a loss. I have been working on fixing this for 4 hours now with no success. I appreciate your time to look at it. I must be doing something wrong. No matter what i do it wont create a pop up alert even though the form is invalid when i press submit.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../play2learn/contact-us.js"></script>
<title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section>
            <h1>Play2Learn Logo</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="contains"><a>Games</a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="math-facts.html">Math Facts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    <hr>
    <main>
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
            <div>
            <label for="emailfield">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="emailfield" id="emailfield" required>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="subjectfield">Subject:</label>
            <input type="subject" name="subjectfield" id="subjectfield" required>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="messagefield">Message:</label>
            <input type="message" name="messagefield" id="messagefield" required minlength="5" maxlength="65">
            </div>
            <div>
            <button>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
</body>
<hr>
<footer>&copy; 2022 Play2Learn</footer>
    <address>
        <a href="contact-us.html">
        <img src="images/email.png" alt="email-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com">
        <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com">
        <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://facebook.com">
        <img src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="facebook-icon"></a>
    </address>
</section>
</html>

This is my javaScript:
function checkField(field) {
    if (!field.checkValidity()) {
        field.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    } else {
        field.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }   
}
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');
    const emailField = form.emailfield;
    const subjectField = form.subjectfield;
    const message = form.messagefield;

    emailField.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    checkField(emailField);
    });
    subjectField.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    checkField(subjectField);
    });
    messageField.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    checkField(messageField)
    });
    form.addEventListener('Submit', function(e){
    checkField(emailField);
    checkField(subjectField);
    checkField(messageField);
    
    if(!form.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fix form errors.');
    } else {
        alert('Form Submitted');
     }
   });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some issues with your code.

1. If you find yourself writing the same code over and over again, such as with `checkField`, it usually means you could be using a loop.
2. On submit, you usually want to `e.preventDefault()` always - not just when the data is not valid. You can use `form.reset()` to reset all the inputs back to nothing.
3. You only need to pass `e` into the callback of 'addEventListener' when you plan on using it. Otherwise, it just lingers there. In TypeScript, this would throw a compiler error.

**Working solution:**

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#contact-form');
const fields = form.querySelectorAll('input[name]');

const checkFields = () => {
    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (!field.checkValidity()) {
            field.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
            return;
        }
        field.style.backgroundColor = '';
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    checkFields();
    form.addEventListener('input', checkFields);

    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!form.checkValidity()) return alert('Form invalid. Please fix errors.');

        alert('Form submitted successfully!');
        form.reset();
    });
});
```

```html
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
    <div>
        <label for="emailfield">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email-field" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="subjectfield">Subject:</label>
        <input type="subject" name="subject" id="subject-field" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="messagefield">Message:</label>
        <input type="message" name="message" id="message-field" required minlength="5" maxlength="65" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This code does not seem to work. What could it possibly be at this point?

Comment: @NatashaMetrik Which browser are you using? Alerts coming in fine for me on Chrome.

Comment: I am using chrome :( it shows up as a form but it does not turn red when typing and no pop up shows when submitting. Is it because my file path isnt tagged properly in the HTML?

Comment: Probably. Try running the code snippet right here on Stack Overflow and see if it works then

Comment: It seems that that is not the case when i just use a simple prompt

Comment: So it works when i run the snippet on here but do you know why is is not working when i use it on my computer?

Comment: @NatashaMetrik There must be some issue with your environment then. Make sure you've got a `<script>` tag with a `src` attribute which is properly linked. Even put the tag in the `<head>` element maybe (throwing s** at the wall and hoping it sticks tbh).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code. The first one to address though, per your question is the fact that you are listening for a 'Submit' event instead of a 'submit' event.

Along with that there is a typo. It seems like `const message = form.messagefield;` should be `const messageField = form.messagefield;`(variable name change).

After all of that, your html is malformed. I have fixed all of those in the code below.

```js
function checkField(field) {
    if (!field.checkValidity()) {
        field.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
    } else {
        field.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }   
}
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');
    const emailField = form.emailfield;
    const subjectField = form.subjectfield;
    const messageField = form.messagefield;

    emailField.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    checkField(emailField);
    });
    subjectField.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  checkField(subjectField);
    });
    messageField.addEventListener('input', function(e){
    checkField(messageField)
    });
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    checkField(emailField);
    checkField(subjectField);
    checkField(messageField);
    
    if(!form.checkValidity()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Please fix form errors.');
    } else {
        alert('Form Submitted');
     }
   });   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="../normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../play2learn/contact-us.js"></script>
<title>Contact Us</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <section>
            <h1>Play2Learn Logo</h1>
            <nav>
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li class="contains"><a>Games</a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                            <li><a href="anagram-hunt.html">Anagram Hunt</a></li>
                            <li><a href="math-facts.html">Math Facts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
    </header>
    
    <hr>
    
    <main>
        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
        <form id="contact-form" method="post" novalidate>
            <div>
            <label for="emailfield">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="emailfield" id="emailfield" required>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="subjectfield">Subject:</label>
            <input type="subject" name="subjectfield" id="subjectfield" required>
            </div>
            <div>
            <label for="messagefield">Message:</label>
            <input type="message" name="messagefield" id="messagefield" required minlength="5" maxlength="65">
            </div>
            <div>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </main>
<hr>
<footer>&copy; 2022 Play2Learn</footer>
    <address>
        <a href="contact-us.html">
        <img src="images/email.png" alt="email-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://instagram.com">
        <img src="images/instagram.png" alt="instagram-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com">
        <img src="images/twitter-icon.png" alt="twitter-icon"></a>
        <a href="https://facebook.com">
        <img src="images/facebook-icon.png" alt="facebook-icon"></a>
    </address>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bless you sweet angel <3 I have been studying code for about 7 months now, but this is my first real project. I cant believe that one big S would ruin everything haha! also working on a project for 9 hours straight makes your brain tingle a little bit. Thank you soooooo much <3